# GeoDjango with MongoDB

Tags: gdal, geodjango, mongodb, django

Has anyone had experience successfully deploying GeoDjango with MongoDB? Is it possible? If so, how is it as simple as as installing the non-relational fork of Django and setting MongoDB as the backend?

I like the scaling capabilities of MongoDB and the ability to make schema changes without having to migrate my apps, but have had difficulty finding documentation on setting GeoDjango with non-relational backends.

My geospatial queries largely consist of checking for intersections and containment of geometries.